# Script to add attribute value(say name) to some attribute(like id) in multiple form elements with jquery

Tags: jquery

Eg:-

```
<input name="done"/>
```

after script jquery

```
<input name="done" id="done"/>
```

Cannot do this manually on every element.
Many elements don't have name attribute. Leave them unaffected.
I need it to submit forms & validate input via server side ajax(username)

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("*").filter("[name]").attr('id','$("[name]")');
     })
</script>
```

I added the name attribute to these inputs and then I realized they require an id attribute with the same value. I spent a while copy pasting until I realized it should be possible with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be using jQuery's [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method, as follows:

```
$('[name]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('name'));
});
```

**Note:** this will add / overwrite `id`s in ALL elements containing a `name` attribute, including meta elements. If you don't want this, you can use the [`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) method, for example:

```
$('[name]').not('meta').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i needed!!

Comment: Happy to help @devasood :)